# Executable is too big

Tags: angular, size, electron

I want to write a simple App using Electron and Angular 2.
I followed some [tutorials](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/12/15/create-a-desktop-app-with-angular-2-and-electron/) to setup a *Hello World* app and created an executable with Electron-packager. Everything works fine, but the problem is, that the folder, wich contains the executable and its components, is about 230 Megabytes. 
Is there a way to minimize the size of it? I know i could create a Zip-file and a setup, but that is not what i want to do, the goal is to reduce the size of the installed folder.

The package.json I used:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager . myApp --platform=win32 --arch=x64"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.37.5",
    "electron-packager": "^6.0.2",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "webpack": "^1.12.15",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
        "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typings":"^0.7.11"
  },
    "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.14",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
     "systemjs": "0.19.25"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. Please provide more information about your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Electron distribution itself is relatively large you can't do much here, check electron-packager options and find build output dir, it should have size about 40-100Mb.

Comment: Ok, thats sad, because that will be the main reason why my company is not going to use it